# How do I add an image to a label?

Tags: c#, image, label, fromfile

I have to add image to my label, but I can't find solution how to do this.
I'm trying by use this:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        url = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Cards/cardSkin.png";
        mylabel.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(url)));
```

I don't know even if I'm using this right, I just copied this from others project what we did with class.
Anyway, I tried to create `Image img = Image.FromFile("YourFile.bmp");` but I don't why, `.FromFile` wasn't working for me.
Anyone of you guys have the other way to make label as picture(background) and help newbie do this? :D

Thrown Exception:

```
Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromFile.
```

Comment: What's the code for?What kind of label it is (winform, wpf, silverlight)? What are you trying to do and what's the problem except "not working"?

Comment: Well, it didn't work, because there are different Image classes in .NET. You've tried to use a method from System.Drawing.Image on System.Windows.Controls.Image. I don't know anything about Windows Forms, but take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg145045.aspx - it's the best source of knowledge about API.

Comment: It's wpf label. Im doing the 21 game (blackjack) and I have to make label as card picture. Im trying to create Image class, but FromFile doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Adding Image to a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891155/c-sharp-adding-image-to-a-label)

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
Label ilabel = new Label(); // create a label
Image i = Image.FromFile("image.png"); // read in image
ilabel.Size = new Size(i.Width, i.Height); //set label to correct size
ilabel.Image = i; // put image on label
this.Controls.Add(ilabel); // add label to container (a form, for instance)
```

Comment: Note: I found a Label to be inadequate and soon switched to a Button, because I wanted the OnClick event.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Label created in the Form designer, make sure to set `AutoSize` to false. Otherwise the `.Width` will be 0 because the text is empty and modifying the `.Size` is ignored.

Code like this will work:

```
label1.Image?.Dispose(); // prevent memory leak
var image = Image.FromFile(@"image.png");
label1.Size = image.Size;
label1.Image = image;
```