# Loading Image through label

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to load an image through label using this code

```
private void getData()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = MejOnlineManagementDB00;Integrated Security=True;");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT empName,empLname,empMi,empImage
                                            FROM employees
                                            WHERE empName = '"+ ddlAvail.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() +"'", conn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                lblName.Text = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(); 
                lblLname.Text = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                lblMi.Text = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                lblImage.Text = "<img runat='server' src='" + rdr.GetValue(3).ToString() + "'></img>";
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

every time I select a dropdownlist value it generates me set of sql data.My only problem is the image.Cause it wont load any image at all.The filepath on my visual studio and image name is correct.
This is an example of my image 
../Images/Profile/logo.jpg
I save the images filepath on my database.

Comment: what is your image stored as in the server? If it's a byte array see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane its jpg I think or any image file extension.Im using the filepath to pull the specific name of the image in the server using sql.

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: @jamiedanq it wont show the image.My file path and filename is correct.

Comment: @jamiedanq I see so I need to change the value type of my label?

Comment: @jamiedanq I'll try this.But in this way I couldnt adjust its width and size using my css?

Comment: you should be able to that still

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109664/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-jamiedanq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine

Make sure the file path your are retrieving from the database exists and the path isn't returning any unwanted characters.

That is:

```
rdr.GetValue(3).ToString()  //should return the right path (string)
```

It should be fine. Hope this helped

Comment: @barry I had just changed my my file parh turns out it s wrong.Jamiedanq helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It won't ever show the image because all that your code is doing is setting the text on the label.

If you want to display the image try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.image(v=vs.110).aspx) , or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848341/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-a-label).