# I want to display an image from the database in a label in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

This is my database:

```
create table images 
(
     ID int primary key identity, 
     Name nvarchar(255),
     Size int, 
     ImgData varbinary(max) 
)

CREATE PROCEDURE UploadImages
     @Name nvarchar(255),
     @Size int,
     @ImgData varbinary(max),
     @NewId int output
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO images
    VALUES (@Name, @Size, @ImgData)

    SELECT @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()    
END
```

I want to display image from database into label - how can I do that in asp.net?

This is my code:

```
 HttpPostedFile PostedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;

 string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
 string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
 int fileSize = PostedFile.ContentLength;

 if(fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".bmp"|| fileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
 {
     Stream stream = PostedFile.InputStream;
     BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);

     byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

     string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UploadImages", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         con.Open();

         SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter()
         {
             ParameterName = "@Name",
             Value = fileName
         };
         cmd.Parameters.Add(paramName);

         SqlParameter paramSize = new SqlParameter()
         {
             ParameterName = "@Size",
             Value = fileSize
         };
         cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSize);

         SqlParameter paramImgData = new SqlParameter()
         {
             ParameterName = "@ImgData",
             Value = bytes
         };
         cmd.Parameters.Add(paramImgData);

         SqlParameter paramNewId = new SqlParameter()
         {
             ParameterName = "@NewId",
             Value =-1,
             Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
         };
         cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNewId);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();

         Lmas.Visible = true;
         Lmas.Text = "done";
         Lmas.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
         HyperLink1.Visible = true;
         HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/ShowImage.aspx?Id=" + cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value.ToString();

         //LoadImage();
     } 
 } 
 else 
 {
     Lmas.Visible = true;
     Lmas.Text = "only images (.jpg .png .gif .bmp) can be uploaded";
     Lmas.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     HyperLink1.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848341/how-do-i-add-an-image-to-a-label

Comment: What you tried to do? All I see that you save image into DB and nothing about show image in the label.

Comment: I tried to call my DB into label but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy fix is:

```
 <img id="img" runat="server" alt=""/> (instead of an label)
```

and in your function

```
img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])datarow[0]);
```

Comment: I try it but doesnt reconize .src

Comment: you do get the img-tag?

Comment: opps, i was made it by asp.net but now i changed it , but i have red line under datarow says: it used like a variable

Comment: you need to replace datarow[0] for your variable that contains the byte-array.

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: byte[] sevenThousandItems = CreateSpecialByteArray(7000);

public static byte[] CreateSpecialByteArray(int length)
    {
        var arr = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 0x20;
        }
        return arr;
    }
Is that right?

Comment: Why not just reading it out of the DB? In the page where you want to put your image you need to read out the column/record from the db.
in your code that you posted the following would be good: img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Comment: string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageById", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter paramID = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@ID",
                Value = Request.QueryString["ID"]
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramID);

Comment: con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])sevenThousandItems);
        }
    }
    public static byte[] CreateSpecialByteArray(int length)
    {
        var arr = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 0x20;
        }
        return arr;
    }

Comment: why arr[i] = 0x20 ?

Comment: If i want to display  images in anther page i should copy all of the code?

Comment: I hope for you that you have a repository where you can call your logic every time. But yeah, in essential yes. So in your new page something like: var imgByteArray = ImagesRepository.GetImageByteArray(id);
and then you can img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imgByteArray);

Comment: img.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
It work but i should clink on HyperLink1, i want when i click on upload the image display in Default.aspx . that is my code

Comment: string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageById", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: SqlParameter paramID = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@ID",
                Value = Request.QueryString["ID"]
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramID);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;